# $on Not Communicating With $Scope When Used With ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Basically, I am unable to update my controller information when I listen for the $on event if I loaded my html dynamically using ng-include. [Plunker example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/gj21gbqcH1Cm1c0NW4Sv?p=preview)

If you click once, you'll see the view keeps the original $scope.name.  If you click again it will update.

I put a setTimeout on the broadcast to make sure the ng-include was loaded.  You can set that to as long as you want, and will never be able to update the $scope on the first try (at least in my example).

Thoughts?

EDIT:

I'm using `<ng-include="template"></ng-template>`

As an area I can load alternate content in.  If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout()` is a function out of the control of AngularJS, so AngularJS will not automatically run a `digest` after the callback runs. That means, your `$rootScope.$broadcast()` was run, but AngularJS didn't realize that. The next time when you use `$rootScope.template = '....';`, a digest runs, and the view was updated to the previous run's model.

To solve the problem, you will need to manually call `$scope.$apply()` at the end of your `setTimeout()` callback, or use the Angular-wrapped version of `setTimeout()`, which is `$timeout()`, that will automatically run a digest afterwards.

Please refer to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope) for more details about digest/apply:

Comment: Can I ask if you think this is a reasonable to way to load dynamic templates?  It works, but it does seem silly using $timeout.  Matt Way mentioned below that there is an onload function.  But I can't see how I would communicate between controllers at that point.  In my real world application, I am sending objects from one controller to another.

Comment: @HowardZoopaloopa You don't really need to send objects from one controller to another very often. In most cases, it can be done by abstracting a service instead of leaving heavy logics & data exchange in controllers.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me if you use `$timeout` instead of setTimeout. Which you should be using for angular applications.

```
$timeout(function(){
     $rootScope.$broadcast('BROADCAST', param);
}, 1000);
```

There is definitely something wrong with your design if you are trying to do something like this though. Perhaps someone could suggest an alternate solution if you better explained what you are trying to achieve. As you cannot possibly know how long the timeout *should* be.

Comment: Timeout is insuring I have my template loaded in time for the broadcast call.  What would you suggest I do instead?  I'm only trying to do what the example shows.

Comment: Have you looked at the `onload` attribute associated with `ng-include`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Comment: It looks interesting, I just wouldn't know how to communicate with c2 at that point.  The onload would bubble up to it's parent controller, not the controller of the loaded div.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1) First, do not define the $scope.template in the broadcast function.  The ngInclude will not have a file to display until that value is set; so from it makes sense--in my mind--that the template would not be able to make changes before it and the controller are loaded.

2) You never actually apply Controller C2 to the ngInclude.  You can do that like:

```
  <ng-include src="template" ng-controller="c2"></ng-include>
```

Once I do these two things, the code works and updates the first time without the use of the setTimeout() at all.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9sOdWKA5X0QA1WuBwY9h?p=preview)

Comment: I'm looking to load different templates in that template area that might have different controllers.  This is why I'm not defining the template in the function.  For instance, in that template space, I may want to load c3.html etc... make sense?